# R shiny : change background color based on input

Tags: r, shiny, colors, background, reactive

I'm pretty new to R shiny and I've got the following ui:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(textOutput("title")),
    selectInput("tool", "Choose your tool",
                choices = c("Tool 1", "Tool 2",
                            "Tool 3"),
                selected = "Tool 1", multiple = FALSE
                )
)
)
```

What I want to do is change the background color of the whole web page based on the result of the select input "tool". For example, if the user selects "Tool 1", the background color would be red; if the user selects "Tool 2", the background color would be orange, and so on.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways to do it but this solution works. The idea is to render a UI each time input$tools changes so that tags$style can be modified.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("tool", "Choose your tool",
                choices = c("Tool 1", "Tool 2",
                            "Tool 3"),
                selected = "Tool 1", multiple = FALSE),
    
    uiOutput('background_change') )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    bg <- reactive({
        case_when(input$tool =='Tool 1' ~ 'body {
                                             background-color: red;
                                             color: white;
                                        }',
                  input$tool =='Tool 2' ~ 'body {
                                            background-color: orange;
                                            color: white;
                                        }',
                  input$tool =='Tool 3' ~ 'body {
                                            background-color: brown;
                                            color: white;
                                        }',
      TRUE  ~ 'body {
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
                }')
    })
    
    
    
    output$background_change <- renderUI({
        tagList(fluidPage(tags$style(HTML(bg()))))
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```